# Sending email with python script

Tags: python, email, smtp, yahoo-api

What I'm trying to do is get my python code to send an email. This code is supposed to use the yahoo smtp to send the email. I don't need any attachments or anything else. The code bugs out where it says `Error: unable to send email.` Other than the obvious of putting in correct email receiver and sender addresses, what can I do to get this thing to work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from smtplib import SMTP
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL
from smtplib import SMTPException
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import sys

#Global varialbes
EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Email from Python script"
EMAIL_RECEIVERS = ['receiverId@gmail.com']
EMAIL_SENDER  =  'senderId@yahoo.com'
TEXT_SUBTYPE = "plain"

YAHOO_SMTP = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
YAHOO_SMTP_PORT = 465

def listToStr(lst):
    """This method makes comma separated list item string"""
    return ','.join(lst)

def send_email(content, pswd):
    """This method sends an email"""
    msg = MIMEText(content, TEXT_SUBTYPE)
    msg["Subject"] = EMAIL_SUBJECT
    msg["From"] = EMAIL_SENDER
    msg["To"] = listToStr(EMAIL_RECEIVERS)

    try:
      #Yahoo allows SMTP connection over SSL. 
      smtpObj = SMTP_SSL(YAHOO_SMTP, YAHOO_SMTP_PORT)
      #If SMTP_SSL is used then ehlo and starttls call are not required.
      smtpObj.login(user=EMAIL_SENDER, password=pswd)
      smtpObj.sendmail(EMAIL_SENDER, EMAIL_RECEIVERS, msg.as_string())
      smtpObj.quit();
    except SMTPException as error:
      print "Error: unable to send email :  {err}".format(err=error)

def main(pswd):
    """This is a simple main() function which demonstrates sending of email using smtplib."""
    send_email("Test email was generated by Python using smtplib and email libraries", pswd);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """If this script is executed as stand alone then call main() function."""
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print "Please provide password"
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Please read the help centre before asking questions. This question does not clearly state what the problem is. Read the article "How to Ask a Question" before posting

Comment: Also, the default email addresses are still there

Comment: I know the default email addresses are still there. I said that in the post. When I change the default addresses it still doesn't work.

Comment: and sorry for not being clear and not knowing the rules here. The problem is that the code as is does not send an email. I cannot pinpoint the exact problem, which is why I'm here asking the rest of the community if anyone else has an idea

Comment: Perhaps remove the except line and give us the error then? The generic message is not for debugging in this case

Comment: Also, you can 'learn the rules here' by reading the help center

Comment: ok. will do on the help center.

Comment: after removing the except line, the error it gives is invalid syntax. on the def main(pswd) line

Comment: Also remove the try line and indent them as they should be.

Comment: As well as the print line.

Comment: it now runs through the entire script successfully but still not working as it should. I know it's not actually doing what it's supposed to be doing because I switched out my real email with a fake email to see if it would still run and it did. It runs all the way through, just not working as intended

Comment: Then what is it not doing that you intend? Please be specific. If it runs through successfully, then it should sent the email.

Comment: well, that's exactly the problem. What I intend is for it to send the email. It is running all the way through and not sending the email.

Comment: Are you using a yahoo email address to send the email?

Comment: yes. I've quadruple checked that

Comment: Did you include your password as a command line argument?

Comment: You now have an answer to your question. If it answers your question, then please mark it as accepted as well as upvoting it.

Comment: I replaced every "pswd" in the script with my actual password.

Comment: That's the problem then - you need to run the program in the command line like so: `python the_script_name_goes_here.py yourpassword`. Revert the script to fix the changes you made to `pswd`

Comment: sorry for still not having solved this but the code still does not send the email as you would think. I put in the command line 'python scriptname.py password'. the code runs through completely but no email is sent. been brainstorming but to no avail. i also tried 'python scriptname.py username password' and same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a yahoo email address of my own. Hopefully somebody else in the community can help you

Comment: thanks for taking your time to help me out anyways. Hopefully someone else in the community can give it a shot or hopefully I'll figure it out from here. Thanks though

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Yahoo, but Google blocked the login via their smtp-port.
It would be way too easy to conduct brute force attacks otherwise. So even if your code is perfectly ok, the login might still fail because of that. I have tried to do the exact same thing for my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

As developer I suggest: [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail)